# What is the /oem partition?

Tags: ota-update, partitions

Recently I had an over-the-air (OTA) update fail because the /oem partition did not pass the assert. However, it looks like the update still "succeeded" in that the /system partition had all the updated bits and the update check in Android says I'm at the latest version. I'm guessing my /oem partition is outdated now but it doesn't seem to be affecting anything.

What is the purpose and capabilities of the /oem partition?

Comment: manufacturer storage?

Comment: right but how does it work and what can it do? for example, my system partition got updated via OTA but it errored out during oem partition upgrade and the version in my About Phone was wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The /oem partition is used for any carrier customisations to the Android firmware; if your firmware build is not a carrier-specific one then it might be empty anyway.  This purpose is described in the [Android Project Treble documentation](https://source.android.com/security/selinux/images/SELinux_Treble.pdf).